What is "double..." in Java
I was coding some project using Efficient Java Matrix Library (EJML), and I came upon at the ".setRow()" method. In the docs of EJML, ".setRow()" method explained as:
public void setRow(int row,
 int startColumn,
 double... values)
Assigns consecutive elements inside a row to the provided array.

A(row,offset:(offset + values.length)) = values

Parameters:
row - The row that the array is to be written to.
startColumn - The initial column that the array is written to.
values - Values which are to be written to the row in a matrix.


as you can see, they used a variable called "double...", which seems different from "double" or "Double". What is it?
I tried to search online in forums, reddit etc. but couldn't find any explanation. I also checked EJML's docs for an explanation, but couldn't find there either.

... in most languages is the spread operator, and is typically shorthand for "many variables of the same type" (so double... values instead of double value1, double value2, double value3, and so on). This article (and now the linked duplicate) says it's called varargs in Java

The type double.. is identical with double[] only that you can have 0, 1, 2, and more argument (variable-arguments parameter).

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function#In_Java
